# ¿Por qué no me ejecuta la función exec() o shell_exec() php desde un navegador?

Tags: php, exec

Quiero ejecutar esta instrucción(copiar un archivo local a un servidor remoto) desde una página web, pero no me la ejecuta y en línea de comandos si lo hace. ¿Qué estará mal?

```php
$resultado = shell_exec('scp 272x100_logo.png user@hostname:/var/www/html/index/img/');
echo "Salida: $resultado\n";
```

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so], te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primera medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tus preguntas y que sean bien recibidas por la comunidad.

Comment: ¿El archivo que deseas copiar está en el equipo en el que usas el navegador o en el servidor? ¿Para conectarte por ssh debes teclear contraseña o has configurado el par de  claves pública/privada?

Answer (score 0):

Intenta utilizar la ruta compelat en la ejecucion del comando

```
$resultado = shell_exec('scp /ruta/directorio/272x100_logo.png user@hostname:/var/www/html/index/img/');
echo "Salida: $resultado\n";
```

Al ejecutar algunos comando desde php, la ruta se modifica de la funciona exec(), por lo que es posible que el archivo no exista o este dirigida a otro lugar.